# Detect delete in RecyclerView item with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

In my App I have a list of plants and the user can insert new ones, modify and delete them.

The user can longClick one of the items of the list to delete it but **if someone else delete the same item from another device or me from database the List doesn't update** like in the edit (the item stays in the list and you can also delete it again which makes no sense).

Here is my way to update the item when data changes:

```
PlantViewHolder(View itemView, Context context) {
        super(itemView);
        cardView = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        plantCommonName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.plantCommonName);
        plantScientificName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.plantScientificName);
        plantPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.plantPhoto);
        plantCategory = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.plantCategory);
        plantDescription = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.plantDescription);
        plantPrice = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.plantPrice);
        plantStock = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.plantStock);
        this.context = context;

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);

        database.getReference().child("plants").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot dss: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Plant p0 = dss.getValue(Plant.class);
                    editAt(p0);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                Log.w("Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is the method:

```
private void editAt(Plant p0) {
    for(int i = 0; i < plants.size(); i++) {
        if(plants.get(i).getID() == p0.getID()) {
            plants.get(i).setCommonName(p0.getCommonName());
            plants.get(i).setScientificName(p0.getScientificName());
            plants.get(i).setPrice(p0.getPrice());
            plants.get(i).setStock(p0.getStock());
            plants.get(i).setSeason(p0.getSeason());
            plants.get(i).setDescription(p0.getDescription());

            notifyItemRangeChanged(i, plants.size());
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I just modify the specific item in the List but I have no idea how to differentiate or implement delete in the database listener.
How can I detect if an item is deleted from the database and remove it with `ValueEventListener`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by getting the snapshot from `onChildRemoved` and checking in the List if this ID is in this snapshot.

```
database.getReference().child("plants").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Plant p0 = dataSnapshot.getValue(Plant.class);
                editAt(p0);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Plant p0 = dataSnapshot.getValue(Plant.class);
                for(int i = 0; i < plants.size(); i++) {
                    if(plants.get(i).getID() == p0.getID()) {
                        plants.remove(i);
                        notifyItemRemoved(i);
                        notifyItemRangeChanged(i, plants.size());
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `ValueEventListener` to remove a value. Just find your `reference` and than use `removeValue()` method. Assuming you have a node named `Plants` please use this code:

```
yourReference.child("Plants").child(plantId).removeValue();
```

In which `plantId` is the particulat plant you want to delete.

If you want to verify if an item exists, take your `reference`, and than use on the `SanpShop` the method `exists()`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm not using valueEventListener to delete it, I'm using `                            database.getReference().child("plants").child(dss.getKey()).removeValue();
` but I want to automatically delete it from de List item when another user delete this item from another device and I'm trying to use `exists()` in the valueEventListener to detect this change but seems it doesn't work.

Comment: Than you need to use `notifyDataSetChanged()` method an your `adapter` like this: `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: I solved it by using `ChildEventListener` thanks for the help anyways.